# How can I automate the sequence of dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe:

```
     *Ca *O *Ca  Ca  Hy
0    1   2   3   4   5
1    1             
2    1    5            
3    1    6  7   8            
4    5                
5    6         
6    6                
7    6                
8    9              
9    9  12          
10   9  9   10   11
```

Desired dataframe will look like:

```
     *Ca *O *Ca  Ca  Hy
0    1   2   3   4   5
1    1             
2    1    5            
3    1    6  7   8            
4    5                
5    6         
6    6                
7    6                
8    9              
9    9   12          
10   9    9   10   11
11   10   12  13  14   15
12   10   15
13   10   16  17   18  
14   10
15   15
16   16
17   16
18   16
.........
```

That equivalent to:
`Ca[i]` = `a` and `Ca[i+10]` = `a+10` but `Ca[i+9]` =! `a+9` We can say that i `=>` 10
I want to get the sequence every 10 rows in a range of 250.
Hopefully, it is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC,

```
pd.concat([df, df+10], ignore_index=True)
```

Or perhaps:

```
pd.concat([df+i for i in range(0, 250, 10)], ignore_index=True).head(40)
```

Well looky there, @piRSquared sighting.....

```
pd.concat(map(df.add, range(0, 250, 10)), ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: In range `250`?

Comment: `pd.concat(map(df.add, range(0, 250, 10)), ignore_index=True)`

Comment: @piRSquared How are you doing?  Staying healthy?

Comment: always get this error!  `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`

Comment: I'm good.  You?  It's nice to peruse 'ol question/answers again (-:

Comment: Note that `[df] + [df + i for i in range(10, 250, 10)]` can be simplified to `[df + i for i in range(0, 250, 10)]]`

Comment: I think I did something wrong: df.fillna('', inplace=True) df = df.astype(int) I need to fill NAN with nothing '' but I can not convert it to int

Comment: Yep, you can't convert '', empty string to int.  Do you want zeroes instead?

Comment: NO, just empty cell

Comment: Well, you can't encode an empty cell to a int.